# Using custom Data Service Providers, do I have any control over URLs that are returned?

Tags: url, .net-4.0, wcf-data-services

I'm implementing several custom Data Service Providers in [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx):

- [IDataServiceMetadataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.providers.idataservicemetadataprovider(VS.100).aspx)
- [IDataServiceQueryProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.providers.idataservicequeryprovider(VS.100).aspx)
- [IDataServiceUpdateProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.providers.idataserviceupdateprovider(VS.100).aspx)

To illustrate the point of my question consider this made-up example:

I have a resource called "Employee," which can be addressed in the following ways:

`MyDataService.svc/Employees(1)`

or

`MyDataService.svc/Employees?$filter=FirstName eq 'John'`

The results that are returned automatically include URLs for each resource, like:

`http://localhost:1337/MyDataService.svc/Employees(5)`, and so on.

Is it possible to, instead, have Data Services return `People(5)` instead of `Employees(5)`?

In short, I need some control over URLs that Data Services generates. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not seem possible at this time.